# Chess: Get All Legal Moves Python

Tags: python, chess

Here is my code so far:

```
from colorama import init, Back, Fore
init()



def create_board():
    letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
    numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
    board = {}
    for number in numbers:
        for letter in letters:
            board[letter + number] = letter + number
    return board

def print_pieces(square_board):
    letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]

    pawn_squares = ["a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "g2", "h2", "a7", "b7", "c7", "d7", "e7", "f7", "g7", "h7"]
    knight_squares = ["b1", "g1", "b8", "g8"]
    rook_squares = ["a1", "h1", "a8", "h8"]
    queen_squares = ["e1", "e8"]
    king_squares = ["d1", "d8"]
    bishop_squares = ["c1", "f1", "c8", "f8"]
    piece_squares = {"pawn_squares": pawn_squares, "knight_squares": knight_squares, "bishop_squares": bishop_squares, "rook_squares": rook_squares, "king_squares": king_squares, "queen_squares": queen_squares}
    pieces = {"pawn": "♙", "king": "♚", "queen": "♛", "rook": "♜", "bishop": "♝", "knight": "♞"}
    board = square_board
    piece = ["pawn", "knight", "bishop", "rook", "king", "queen"]

    for square in board:
        for pces in piece:
            if board[square] in piece_squares[f"{pces}_squares"]:
                board[square] = pieces[pces]

    letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
    numbers = ["3", "4", "5", "6"]
    squares = []
    for letter in letters:
        for number in numbers:
            squares.append(letter + number)

    for square in squares:
        board[square] = " "

    board = dict(reversed(list(board.items())))
    return board

def draw_board(board):
    colors = [Back.MAGENTA, Back.YELLOW]
    line = 0
    squares = 0
    color = Fore.RESET
    for square in board:
        if line == 8:
            print(color + Back.RESET + "\n", end="")
            colors = colors[::-1]
            line = 0
        if squares == 48:
            color = Fore.BLACK
        print(color + colors[0] + board[square], flush=True, end=" ")
        colors = colors[::-1]
        squares += 1
        line += 1

board = create_board()
draw_board(print_pieces(board))
```

This works by storing each square in a dictionary and what is on the square (- indicates nothing on the square).

I want to list all possible legal moves (castling, en passant, promotion not included), given the state of the board.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?
My code is kind of messy, and I understand this is not really the best approach on making a chess board.

Comment: I don't think there's a non-messy way to find all legal moves in chess. Every piece moves differently, and there are lots of corner cases.

Comment: There are very likely too many legal moves for them to be calculated (and stored) in a reasonable amount of time — otherwise it would be impossible to beat a computer program. What you want to do is a fool's errand…

Comment: @martineau The difficulty of coming up with a good chess program isn't because there are too many possible legal moves - at most there is an upper bound of 1024 moves (16 pieces * 64 squares). Instead, it's because it's hard to calculate which moves are good.

Comment: @SuperStormer: The reason it's hard to calculate which moves are good is (more than partially) because there are so many of them.

Comment: I'm not sure if we're supposed to use the flag function for incorrect information on SO, but @martineau I am afraid you're just flat out wrong in this case.

As for the question, have you considered using the [python-chess](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library instead? It would make all of this a whole lot easier.

Comment: @MickMcCarthy: When I said "too many legal moves" I was not thinking of merely the next possible move, but of all the possibilities following each one of them, etc, etc. i.e an exhaustive enumerating them all. Even for "only" an upper bound of 1024, the number of  them grows rapidly the further one "looks ahead". I did not mean that just finding the next set of "legal" moves was impractical.

Comment: @martineau, the average number of legal moves in any given position is around 20-30. All chess engines calculate legal moves in some way, even with some of the easier methods you will get a chess engine that will never lose to a good human. As an intermediate programmer I made chess engines in both Python and C# which would beat any good chess player. As for looking ahead, I made it to around 8 moves (half moves) ahead with my limited understanding, masters like Stockfish reaches depths of much more.

Comment: @martineau Right, but that's not how chess engines work, and it's also not what OP asked. They asked for all possible legal moves given a single board state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of ways of representing a chess board and then calculating all legal moves in a given position.

The easiest way which is also reasonable fast is to represent the board as a 1D array/list. You can read more about this on e.g. [Chessprogramming.org](https://www.chessprogramming.org/10x12_Board). The way I usually do it is to have a -2 on places which are outside of the board (these will always be on the same indexes are are only used to calculate legal moves), -1 on empty squares, and a number if there is a piece on the square (0 for white pawn, 1 for white knight and so on).

There is too much complexity and code specific things in giving you code for move generation here. I suggest you look at Chessprogramming.org which has all you need for learning about programming a chess engine, there are also some good Youtube tutorials you can follow.